# Create device height background element

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter so please be fair. 
I would like to create the following.

Layout

- Background which is always the entire screen-size (includes multiple stacked images)
- Content (adapts to the the normal app ui behaviours -> ui element like keyboard)

I can't seem to figure out how to create this background element which should not resize when the keyboard is pulled out.

I have this and I hope someone could give me a hand.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var insetHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height + insetHeight,
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          SizedBox(
            width: 370,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: PageScrollPhysics(), // dont really need this
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Text("Login to",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Opensans",
                            fontSize: 30,
                            letterSpacing: .6,
                            color: Colors.black45,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0), child: LoginForm()),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to use the `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;` but it's always returning 0.

I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For background, Try following:

1. Create a variable `Size _screensize` in `_MyHomePageState`.
2. Override `initState` in `_MyHomePageState` and do following:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
   _screenSize ??= MediaQuery.of(context).size;`
}
```

3. Use this `_screenSize` as `width` and `height` for `Positioned` as below:

```
    Positioned(
      width: _screenSize.width,
      height: _screenSize.height,
     ),
```

Add other normal widgets as usual.

Summary for background:

`step 1`: creating a private reference for size to use.

`step 2`: updating the private size variable only when it is null, which is only when the widget state is initialized the first time.

`step 3`: using private size as height and width for the background.

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately we need the context variable, which does not exist within the initBuild function.

Comment: Have you tried this approach. I think context is available in the initState. Check this out: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html

Answer (score 0):

The `Scaffold` rebuilds its body when keyboard is visible.

So move your background widget outside the `Scaffold`.

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox.expand(
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/background.png",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //Should be transparent
          body: Center(
            child: TextField(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```